# When should Smoke and Adhoc testing to be done

Tags: manual-testing

I am new to the Software Testing, I wanted to know when we can perform smoke and Adhoc in Practical

Also if you guys can provide me some good link that I can refer that also usefull

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Smoke testing determines the stability of a deployed software build. As a result of the smoke test, the QA team can proceed with further software testing.

**When to do Smoke Testing:**

- As soon as QA gets the build
- When a company gives the build/software to the customer, chances are their team might miss copying a few files/installing the software. The customer will do smoke testing
- Release engineer/ Build engineer will do smoke testing to check to build is installed properly in the testing/ Production environment
- Before giving the build to QA, the dev team will do smoke testing

**Advantage:**

- QA can find the defect at the early stage itself
- Dev team will get sufficient time to fix the defect
- Test cycle will not be postponed and release will not be delayed

**Resources for Smoke testing:**

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smoke-testing-software-testing/
- https://www.guru99.com/smoke-testing.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmoI2q5c0QI

---

**Adhoc Testing:** Testing the application randomly without looking at the requirement

**Why to do Adhoc testing:**

- Customers can use the application randomly
- Developing the application as per the requirement is not sufficient
- Breaking the system

**When to do Adhoc Testing:**

- When their limited time in hand to test the system.
- When there are no clear test cases to test the product.
- When formal testing is completed.
- When the development is mostly complete.

**Why we should not do Adhoc at the early stage:**

- As Test Engineer first, we always test application is testable or not
- Customers will use the application in a positive way
- In the beginning only if we spend more time doing Adhoc testing, chances are there you might not get sufficient time to do positive testing

**Resources for Adhoc testing:**

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adhoc-testing-in-software/
- https://www.guru99.com/adhoc-testing.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/adhoc_testing.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wob3hixGneY

Comment: Sure will update

Comment: Updated Please have a look and let me know anything need to be updated